# Java: Double to Integer

Tags: java, casting, integer, double

I know that I cannot convert a Double to Integer directly in java, but I can always do the following to get an Integer from Double,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Double d = 2.3;
  Integer i = d.intValue(); // d.intValue() autoboxed to Integer
  
  System.out.println("Success");
  
}
```

Why doesn't Java give me this capability built in so that I don't have to do this everytime myself?

Comment: Because (I) it's a narrowing (precision-losing) conversion that you can't do without a cast even if you use `double` and `int`, and (ii) you *should* be using `double` and `int` in this kind of code.

Comment: Java does not implicitly convert objects into other objects.

Comment: @khelwood You sure about that? What about `Integer i = 1; Double d = i;`?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne That would give you an `incompatible types` error.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Integer i = 1; Double d = i; does not work as well

Comment: @khelwood, got it -> casting is only for a single object having different types? For eg, Double to Number is possible because 2.0 is a Double as well as a Number. But since Integer is a sibling of Double, 2.0 is not an Integer?

Comment: @mettleap An instance of Double is not an instance of Integer, nor vice-versa, so you can't cast between them, if that's what you mean.

Comment: In other words, casting of an object does not change the object. It merely allows assigning it to a variable of the new type, and it has to actually have an "is_a" relationship with the type you request. The conversion you have described in your question actually creates a new, completely different object, so it cannot be done with a cast.

Comment: @RealSkeptic , right got it now :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can package this code into method.

```java
public static Integer doubleToInteger(Double d){
    return d.intValue();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.